# Mysql, SQLite, Scalability

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Could SQLite be an alternative for mysql in high traffic web sites? 
Thanks

Comment: Our develeopers cache each blocks manually!!! and update each block manually again!!! because mysql overloading issues :D

Comment: Will it be read-only? The database I mean? How frequent do you have writes to the database?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen; Write to database (mysql) directly, write the database to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: SQLite is embedded database. It is purpose is different than standalone RBDMS. While it is quicker with simple queries than MySQL, keep in mind that SQLite has:

- no good networking support (SQLite purpose is different), so replication is PITA
- coarse-grained locking (one write at a time)
- no advanced table statistics
- no sophisticated query optimizer
- high memory consumption with large databases (a 100GB database would require about 25MB or RAM before each transaction)

Then if you do not plan to use SQLite over network, database sizes are quite small, queries are rather simple, and you have a lots of reads (and really small number of writes), then SQLite may be a better choice.

About MySQL: optimizing and using MySQL in super high traffic sites is not for faint hearted. I recommend some good reading:

- http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067
- https://www.packtpub.com/high-availability-mysql-cookbook/book

Answer (score 4):

> SQLite usually will work great as the
>   database engine for low to medium
>   traffic websites (which is to say,
>   99.9% of all websites). The amount of web traffic that SQLite can handle
>   depends, of course, on how heavily the
>   website uses its database. Generally
>   speaking, any site that gets fewer
>   than 100K hits/day should work fine
>   with SQLite. The 100K hits/day figure
>   is a conservative estimate, not a hard
>   upper bound. SQLite has been
>   demonstrated to work with 10 times
>   that amount of traffic.

Source: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Answer (score 2):

No way. SQLLite deals terribly with concurrency. The database would be a huge performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

No! It cannot be!

Comment: Mysql already is not a good solution. We have to using memcache ect or dummy fopen() , fwrite() !

Comment: True. But considering the question between SQLite & MySQL, MySQL stands out. MySQL lags when the load is high.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you push your data to a cache and read from the cache.  SQLite *can* be used as persistence for cache, but its really not recommended.